# UWP AAC encode in Media Foundation library, Class not registered

Tags: uwp, encode, ms-media-foundation, aac

I want to use AACEncode MFT in UWP/Win10.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/aac-encoder

I found in wmcodecdsp.h
there is some definition

```
EXTERN_C const CLSID CLSID_AACMFTEncoder;

#ifdef __cplusplus

class DECLSPEC_UUID("93AF0C51-2275-45d2-A35B-F2BA21CAED00")
AACMFTEncoder;
#endif
```

So..
I try to use

```
EXTERN_GUID(CLSID_AACMFTEncoder, 0x93AF0C51, 0x2275, 0x45D2, 0xA3, 0x5B, 0xF2, 0xBA, 0x21, 0xCA, 0xED, 0x00);

Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<IMFTransform> mftAudio_PCM_To_AAC;
hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_AACMFTEncoder, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IMFTransform, &mftAudio_PCM_To_AAC);
```

I get a hr error-code
"REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG Class not registered"

means I cannot use AAC encode in UWP ??

I also try to manually add mfAACEnd.dll to my UWP project.
It still not work...

Looking for help, thanks.

Comment: In uwp, you can create an encoding profile for AAC audio and then transcode. For more details about it, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/transcode-media-files) to see if it can meet your needs.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [Requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/aac-encoder#requirements) of AAC Encoder, it mentions

> It only supports desktop apps instead of UWP apps.

If you want to use this api, you can create a desktop app and then convert it to the UWP app by using [MSIX Packaging Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/packaging-tool/create-app-package) or creating [Windows Application Packaging Project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net) in visual studio.